# Is there an API for HERE to see your plan / quota

Tags: here-api

I tried looking through the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation), but couldn't find any REST API:s to see your plan / account / quota status.

Also the we page  https://developer.here.com/projects/ seems to render it on the server side. Do I need to scrape that web page or just wait for 429 errors and act accordingly or is there an API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such an API.
At least there was not one year ago, when I asked the same question to our HERE sales person.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to see you plan and You should also get a 429 error from the API, with a message "Limit Exceeded".

If you exceed the Location Services 250,000 Transactions or Data Hub 2.5GB Data transfer or 5GB Database storage included for free in the Freemium plan, **you'll receive an email telling you to add payment details to your account**. You'll have some "wiggle room" above your limits to help ensure your access is not unintentionally shut down. However, it's possible to exceed the threshold, including "wiggle room", which would result in account deactivation, even before we can notify you.

for detail please check the FAQ section with question

```
"12. What happens if I exceed limits on my Freemium plan?"
```

https://developer.here.com/faqs#payment-and-subscription